# map values from a dictionary in a pyspark data frame column based on condition

Tags: pyspark

I have the the below data frame and i would liked the column mapped from a dictionary.

```
data = [
  ('web', '0'),   
  ('web', '1'),
  ('web', '2'),
    ('twitter', '0'),
    ('twitter', '1'),
  ('facebook', '0'),
  ('facebook', '1'),
      ('facebook','2')
]
data = (spark.createDataFrame(data, ['channel','type']))
```

I have the below dictionary and I want the values in the dictionary mapped based on the values of the column 'channel'

```
conf = {'channel_type':
        {'web': {'0': 'website', '1': 'news', '2': 'blogs'},
 'twitter': {'0': 'tweet', '1': 'retweet'},
 'facebook': {'0': 'post',
  '1': 'feed_post',
  '2': 'comment',
  '3': 'shared_post'},
 'you_tube': {'0': 'comment'},
 'instagram': {'0': 'video', '1': 'media', '2': 'comment'},
 'reddit': {'0': 'reddit_post', '1': 'reddit_comment'},
 'linkedin': {'0': 'linkedin_articles',
  '1': 'linkedin_rich',
  '2': 'linkedin_comments'}}
       }
```

I have tried the below code but this has not worked

```
mapping_expr_twitter = f.create_map([lit(x) for x in chain(*conf['channel_type']['twitter'].items())])

mapped_cols = (data.withColumn('channel_type', f.when(f.col('channel')=='twitter',
                                                      mapping_expr_twitter.getItem(f.col("type")))
                              .otherwsie(None))
              )
```

The end result should be if the column 'channel' has web then the column 'type has 0 then the channel type should be 'website'

Answer (score 1):

One way to do is by joining the dataframe but I won't recommend it as joining just to map will be a heavy operation

Other way is to use UDF which is also least recommended as UDF are blackbox and cannot be optimized by catalyst optimizer but still the solutions goes as

```
map_func = f.udf(lambda channel,typ : conf['channel_type'].get(channel,channel).get(typ,typ))
data.withColumn('ChannelType',map_func(f.col('channel'),f.col('type'))).show()

+--------+----+-----------+
| channel|type|ChannelType|
+--------+----+-----------+
|     web|   0|    website|
|     web|   1|       news|
|     web|   2|      blogs|
| twitter|   0|      tweet|
| twitter|   1|    retweet|
|facebook|   0|       post|
|facebook|   1|  feed_post|
|facebook|   2|    comment|
+--------+----+-----------+
```

Another way is to use create_map which is most preferred in this case

```
from itertools import chain
conf_mapper = f.create_map([f.lit(i) for i in chain(*{k+x:y for k,v in conf['channel_type'].items() for x,y in v.items()}.items())])
data.withColumn('ChannelType',conf_mapper[f.concat('channel','type')]).show()

+--------+----+-----------+
| channel|type|ChannelType|
+--------+----+-----------+
|     web|   0|    website|
|     web|   1|       news|
|     web|   2|      blogs|
| twitter|   0|      tweet|
| twitter|   1|    retweet|
|facebook|   0|       post|
|facebook|   1|  feed_post|
|facebook|   2|    comment|
+--------+----+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to restructure your dictionary a little differently, must be possible with a simple python code. Then you can create a dataframe out of it and join. Otherwise , there will be a need of udf which is costly. Since this table is small you can also do a broadcast join.(not shown here)

```
data = [
  ('web', '0'),   
  ('web', '1'),  
    ('twitter', '0'),
    ('twitter', '1')     
]
data_df = (sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, ['channel','type']))
# Changed dictionary structure
conf = [{"channel": 'web', 'type': 0, 'result': 'webbsite'},
            {"channel": 'web', 'type': 1, 'result': 'news'},
            {"channel": 'twitter', 'type': 0, 'result': 'tweet'},
            {"channel": 'twitter', 'type': 1, 'result': 'retweet'}]
 
conf_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data_sub)

data_res = data_df.join(conf_df,on=['channel','type'],how='left')
```

The results :

```
data_res.show()
+-------+----+--------+
|channel|type|  result|
+-------+----+--------+
|    web|   1|    news|
|twitter|   0|   tweet|
|    web|   0|webbsite|
|twitter|   1| retweet|
+-------+----+--------+
```